# How to Get Bootstrap Dropdown value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to fetch the dropdown value when the form submitted.

below is my HTML and javascript code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#gender li").click(function() {
    value = $(this).attr("value");
    gender = $("#gendervalue").val(value);
    //alert(gender);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Gender
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
  <ul id="gender" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Select Gender</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Male</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Female</a></li>
  </ul>
  <input type='hidden' name="gendervalue" id="gendervalue">
</div>
```

when I am submitting the form I am getting gender value [object object]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to get selected items from dropdown like we get dropdown value in normal select element in HTML by value property

Answer (score 0):

I hope it'll help you. Try this code. I've added an explanation in the code comment. T

```
<select id="gender">
<option>Select</option> 
<option value="Male">Male</option>  
<option value="Female">Female</option>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //on change gender value (input value) run this function
        $("#gender").change(function() { 

            //get the value of selected item and store in gender variable
            gender = $("#gender").val();

            //store the value in gender input field. (you can change input type="")
            $("#gendervalue").val(gender);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You used the normal select element but  I don't use this normal select element. I am using bootstrap dropdown which totally different from the select element. There is no value property for that to get the dropdown value

Comment: Which version of bootstrap you are using?

Comment: I am using bootstrap 4